# how to give '*' functions properties to another div in html

Tags: html, css

i have a simple code in css which makes the entire elements of a html page to follow the below property,

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

i just dont want the entire page elements to get those property, instead i want all elements inside a div to take this property, i tried adding it to the div, but it didnt work. how do i do it?

Comment: Does your `div` element have a particular ID or class? If so, just use `#div *`. Without seeing your markup, it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: @BenM i tried it but not working

Comment: take a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9j04anct/1/

Comment: @ZubairShah as I've said, you need to post your markup.

Answer (score 0):

Try too add a class in your div

```
.myclass {
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }    

<div class="myclass"></div>
```

Comment: should be .myclass

Comment: The question says "all elements inside a div", not "a div" and says they tried targetting the div itself already.